# SoftLayer API options to skip some of the returning attributes?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I invoke a REST API like below:

```
GET  https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getCategories.json?objectMask=id;name;categoryCode;groups.prices.item;groups.prices.attributes.itemPriceAttributeType;packageConfigurations.isRequired;packageConfigurations.orderStepId;packageConfigurations.sort
```

I get a response body like below (only part is listed):

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode" : "hub",
      "groups" : [
         {
            "itemCategoryId" : 74,
            "packageId" : 206,
            "prices" : [
               {
                  "attributes" : [],
                  "currentPriceFlag" : null,
                  "id" : 30920,
                  "item" : {
                     "capacity" : "0",
                     "description" : "Object Storage - Pay as you go",
                     "id" : 4069,
                     "itemCategory" : {
                        "categoryCode" : "hub",
                        "groups" : [
                           {
                              "itemCategoryId" : 74,
                              "packageId" : 206,
                              "prices" : [
```

I want to get all of groups.prices.item information, however I do not want the "itemCategory" data that groups.prices.item has.  Is there an option to exclude certain attribute so that the returning data does not include that particular data?  Some other mask to exclude data?

In above response data example, I basically don't want the itemCategory part to be included. This data here:

```
             "itemCategory" : {
                "categoryCode" : "hub",
                "groups" : [
                   {
                      "itemCategoryId" : 74,
                      "packageId" : 206,
                      "prices" : [
```

It seems something changed in SoftLayer API that when I try to do json_encode($catResult) in PHP where the $catResult is the result of SoftLayer_Product_Package::getCategories() and json_encode() function detects recurssion so it terminates.  According to the data that I get using Poster, it may look like a recursion may exist but it actually repeats same data once and not forever.  But then, maybe Poster was smart to just cut it off after the first repeat, but I have no idea it really did that or what I got was the full data from SoftLayer.  In any case, I think I just need a way to not include this "itemCategory" value to work-around the problem.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These articles related to “object masks” may help you:

> https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks
>
> https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/Extended-Object-Masks-taste-things-come
>
> https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest
>
> https://softlayer.github.io/php/monthtodate/

For your case, you need to specify what properties you want to display, for example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getCategories.json?objectMask=mask[id,name,groups[prices[item[id, description]]]]
```

Where: `… [item[id, description]] …` will display only the `id`, `description` of my item (but not `itemCategory`)

Comment: Something like what you mentioned is what I am using as a work-around for now, but I'd like to not list every item attributes. Instead I like to get all that's suppose to return in item except for this one particular attribute and I don't think I've seen a way to specify something like that.

Comment: You're right, when we use "object masks", it is necessary to specify each property that we want to show in the response.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getCategories.json?objectMask=mask[id,name,categoryCode,groups[prices[item,attributes[itemPriceAttributeType]]], packageConfigurations[isRequired, orderStepId, sort]]
```

Comment: Wow.. this actually does the trick of setting "itemCategory" value as null.  How?  Is there difference between using the objectMask=mask[] vs. objectMask= ?  There must be.. From what I can see the objectMask that I set (?objectMask=id;name;categoryCode;groups.prices.item;groups.prices.attributes.itemPriceAttributeType;packageConfigurations.isRequired;packageConfigurations.orderStepId;packageConfigurations.sort) is same as what you set, but you just specified in different ways using the [ ].  Could you offer some explanation on this difference in behavior?

Comment: I think I see that maybe the difference is in the URI which yours uses v3.1 instead of v3 that I was using.  I am using a PHP library and I don't think there's a way to specify to use the v3.1 vs v3.  I just use SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient (serviceName, id, API_ID, API_Key);  How would I get a SoftLayer client that uses this v3.1?  Do I need to pick up an updated library perhaps?  Is there option to specify which version to use?  This is bit outside of question.. but if you know, please tell...

Comment: related to the mask I don't know what is difference between the mask I used and yours :(, the mask I used is called extended-object mask https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/Extended-Object-Masks-taste-things-come. Related your question about php, of course you can change it when you call the getClient method there is a parameter called endpoint there you can specify the URL you wish to use see https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-php-client/blob/master/src/SoapClient.php#L230 .You can send the value https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/